# How to disable a certain version of kernel from autoremoving?

Tags: 16.04, apt

I want to keep some of the old kernels. However, apt-get is always telling me to autoremove those kernels. I now have a big list of programs in the autoremove section, but I can't use autoremove because this would also remove my old kernels. What can I do to disable apt-get autoremove from detecting my old kernels and trying to remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should mark the kernels you want as `hold` using `apt-mark`.

```
sudo apt-mark hold kernel-version
```

For example:

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-headers-4.4.0-77-generic
```

From `man apt-mark`:

> hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the 
>       package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed.

Comment: You mean, all the related kernel-related packages? Like linux-image, linux-image-extra?

Comment: I guess marking the kernel itself works fine, cause the other packages related to kernel will not be removed by apt as they are dependencies of other packages.

Comment: So, if I do not do it, is it still fine? because it seems that they are not seen as dependencies on my system.

Comment: As I know yes it is. However you can test it, it does not have any harm to test, mark a kernel run the autoremove see what happens

Comment: Ok it seems that it's a no, I have to hold linux-image and linux-image-extra as well. But thanks anyway, great help.